# Ubuntu 'Too many levels of symbolic links' when navigating to Documents Directory

Tags: ubuntu

Seeing the following when navigating to my Documents directory on Ubuntu:

```
Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Previous posts suggest that there may be a symbolic link loop here which looks to be confirmed when I run:

```
$ ls -lF Documents
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 23 Jan 14 00:30 Documents -> /home/user/Documents
```

Solution appears to be to remove the symbolic link but when I used unlink on another Directory with the same issue it disappeared and I would like to avoid any documents if possible.

Cause is unknown as I have not made any changes to symbolic links.

Thanks,

TheCube

Comment: Thanks for the response. I followed the suggestions in your link when I initially investigated on a Videos directory with the same issue. This then disappeared and I am concerned I will lose the contents of my Documents directory. Not even sure if there was anything in there but would like to restore the contents if possible

Comment: Do you have a name (or part of a name) of any file that's missing?

Comment: (Side issue, don't use `unlink` when there's a perfectly serviceable `rm`)